# How to store private information like passwords in .net web apis?

Tags: security, keystore, webapi

We are working on a REST api which needs to generate a fingerprint. So it has to store a key and password on its end for generating this fingerprint. Presently, we've stored these values in config file.
But doesn't meet the security requirements. Wanted to know if .net has any better way of storing such key info? Any keystore available similar to Javakeystore?

In general, how to secure critical data in .net Web apis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Key Vault for storing your key and password securely.

Here, how can you configure this,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-portal

Comment: We can't use cloud based service. Any on-prem options?